# Quickest way to convert from CSV to object array

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a large string that comes across the wire using an $.ajax request. I can format the string any way necessary, and currently am using a % as the line delimiter and , as the item delimiter. Considering performance is so essential in my application, does anyone have a quicker way to do the following? Thank You

```
function convertCSV(s) {
    var lines = s.split("%");
    var items, sym, arr = [];

    for (var x = 0, len = lines.length; x < len; x++) {
        items = lines[x].split(",");
        sym = {};
        sym.time = +items[0];
        sym.num1 = +items[1];
        sym.num2 = +items[2];
        sym.a1 = +items[3];
        sym.b1 = +items[4];
        sym.c1 = +items[5];
        sym.d1 = +items[6];
        sym.e1 = +items[7];
        sym.f1 = +items[8];
        sym.g1 = +items[9];
        sym.h1 = +items[10];
        sym.l1 = +items[11];
        arr[x] = sym;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: For optimization of working code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you optimised the server side too? You're likely to find better gains overall looking at small increases on the server side rather than client JS, particularly if you have a large userbase.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps JSON encode what you send over the wire and then JSON decode once you receive it.

Comment: Id also agree that this is a job of the Backend.

Answer (score 1):

A (minor) optimisation:

```
function convertCSV(s) {
  var lines = s.split("%");
  var items, arr = [];
  while ((items = lines.shift()) && (items = items.split(",")) {
    arr.push({ 
        time : +items[0], num1 : +items[1],  num2 : +items[2],
        a1   : +items[3], b1   : +items[4],  c1   : +items[5],
        d1   : +items[6], e1   : +items[7],  f1   : +items[8],
        g1   : +items[9], h1   : +items[10], l1   : +items[11]
     });
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Could be worth experimenting with `Array.shift()` and `Array.pop()`

Comment: I think this might win! I did a jsperf, not sure if I did it correctly though, here: http://jsperf.com/csv-to-object ... Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question would you consider 'accepting' the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I considered the answer, but after testing on multiple browsers there is no answer :(. Each one has better performance with different browsers. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Choose whichever provides the most consistent run time. For example if one function runs very fast on one browser, but very slow on another browser, and another function runs fast on all browsers, but not the fastest, choose the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about speed, you should probably create a simply parser that will parse the string character by character.

Here's a simple example:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/seXwS/1/)

```
function convertCSV(s, properties) {
    var result = [],
        i = 0,
        len = s.length,
        propIndex = 0,
        row = {},
        val = '',
        c;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        switch(c = s[i]) {
            case ',':
                row[properties[propIndex++]] = val;
                val = '';
                break;
            case '%':
                result.push(row);
                row[properties[propIndex++]] = val;
                propIndex = 0;
                row = {};
                val = '';
                break;
            default:
                val += c;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(convertCSV('a,b,c%d,e,f%h,i,j%', ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

---

**EDIT:**

I ran a few performance tests and it seems that I wasn`t right afterall. Your current method is actually the second fastest, but the quickest way to do this seems to be using regular expressions. I must say that I am quite surprised that the simple parser isin't the fastest solution.

[PERFORMANCE TEST](http://jsperf.com/csv-parse-speed)

```
var rx = /(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)%/g,
    result = [],
    match;

while (match = rx.exec(s)) {
    result.push({
        a: match[1],
        b: match[2],
        c: match[3]
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually surprised that regular expressions were faster than `.split()`.

Comment: Very nice! I spent a while compiling another jsperf test using methods on here, and I think @DerFlatulator had the quickest method. Please check out, I could be making a mistake with jsperf. Very interesting stuff! I wonder if I could format the CSV a different way to make it faster, rather than use % and ,. Test here: http://jsperf.com/csv-to-object ... Thanks!

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle Hum, it's hard to tell, however it doesn't seem consistent in all browsers. But logically `shift` shoudln't be used as it technically has to reorder the array for each item you remove a the beginning. I would go for the regex or the Original implementatin of this test http://jsperf.com/csv-to-object/5

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle By the way, a little upvote to Der Flatulator and myself would be appreciated for the effort and time =P